# Preventing column auto sort after editing a bound DataGridView

Tags: vb.net, sorting, datagridview

I've got a DataGridView that has a DataTable as it's Datasource.
Whenever I sort a column and then edit a cell, after editing the column, the column autosorts so the recently edited cell is no longer in the viewable area. Is there any way to prevent this auto sort from happening and only sort when I click on the columns?

Many thanks in advance.

Daryn

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a way of preventing the sort, but you can store the row, column, and sort values of the grid before the update and then restore them after the update.

Here's some of the code I use:

```
Friend Sub refreshGrid()
    Dim row As Integer
    Dim col As Integer
    Dim gridCol As Integer
    Dim gridColsToHide As Integer
    Dim rowCountOrig As Integer
    Dim rowCountNew As Integer

    row = dgvReadOnly.CurrentRow.Index
    col = dgvReadOnly.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex
        Dim sortVal As String

        sortVal = _setSource.DefaultView.Sort
        rowCountOrig = _setSource.Rows.Count
        _setSource = _displaySet.displaySetTable
        rowCountNew = _setSource.Rows.Count
        setRowFilter()
        _setSource.DefaultView.Sort = sortVal
        If (rowCountNew > rowCountOrig) Then  ' added new row
            row = dgvReadOnly.RowCount - 1  ' new row is at bottom of grid, but skip * row
        End If
    dgvReadOnly.DataSource = Nothing
    dgvReadOnly.DataSource = _setSource
    If row >= dgvReadOnly.RowCount - 1 Then   ' after delete
        row = dgvReadOnly.RowCount - 2
    End If
    If row >= 0 Then        ' if didn't delete all rows matching filter
        dgvReadOnly.CurrentCell = dgvReadOnly(col, row)
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this works, but it sounds like it might.

Try setting the SortMode of each column (DataGridView.Columns(1).SortMode) to Programmatic or NotSortable when the cell is selected for editing and then set it to Automatic once you've finished editing.